# datediff in T-SQL case statement throws an overflow error at runtime

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, datediff

The `SELECT` statement below is from a stored procedure that works perfectly without the two date comparison columns, `AFIOTD` and `CustomerOTD`.  (These are intended to return a `1` if `[startdate] <= [enddate]`, else `0`.)  When I enable the columns, my calling code throws an overflow error.

The call is from an `MS Access 2016` VBA module and this SP is running on `MS SQL 2016`.

The stored procedure fills a DAO recordset.

```
SELECT COL.COMMODITY_CODE, Rec.INVOICE_ID, Rec.INVOICE_DATE, Rec.CUSTOMER_ID, Cust.NAME, Cust.ADDR_1, Cust.CITY, Cust.STATE, COL.PART_ID, Bustout.PART_NUMBER, 
               Bustout.AUX, Rec_Line.AMOUNT, ShipLine.SHIPPED_QTY, Shipper.PACKLIST_ID, COL.PROMISE_DATE, COL.DESIRED_SHIP_DATE, 
                CASE
                    WHEN DATEDIFF(day, CAST(Rec.INVOICE_ID AS datetime), CAST(COL.PROMISE_DATE AS datetime)) >= 0
                        THEN CAST(1 AS int)
                        ELSE CAST(0 AS int) 
                END AS AFIOTD, 
                CASE
                    WHEN DATEDIFF(day, CAST(Rec.INVOICE_ID AS datetime), CAST(COL.DESIRED_SHIP_DATE AS datetime)) >= 0
                        THEN CAST(1 AS int)
                        ELSE CAST(0 AS int) 
                END AS CustomerOTD
        FROM   dbo.AFI_PARTS_BUSTOUT AS Bustout RIGHT OUTER JOIN
              AFIRALSRV06.AFI.dbo.SHIPPER_LINE AS ShipLine RIGHT OUTER JOIN
              AFIRALSRV06.AFI.dbo.SHIPPER AS Shipper ON ShipLine.PACKLIST_ID = Shipper.PACKLIST_ID RIGHT OUTER JOIN
              AFIRALSRV06.AFI.dbo.RECEIVABLE_LINE AS Rec_Line ON Shipper.INVOICE_ID = Rec_Line.INVOICE_ID AND Shipper.PACKLIST_ID = Rec_Line.PACKLIST_ID LEFT OUTER JOIN
              AFIRALSRV06.AFI.dbo.CUST_ORDER_LINE AS COL ON Rec_Line.CUST_ORDER_ID = COL.CUST_ORDER_ID AND Rec_Line.CUST_ORDER_LINE_NO = COL.LINE_NO ON 
              Bustout.PART_NUMBER = COL.PART_ID RIGHT OUTER JOIN
              AFIRALSRV06.AFI.dbo.RECEIVABLE AS Rec INNER JOIN
              AFIRALSRV06.AFI.dbo.CUSTOMER AS Cust ON Rec.CUSTOMER_ID = Cust.ID ON Rec_Line.INVOICE_ID = Rec.INVOICE_ID
        WHERE  (Rec.INVOICE_DATE >= CONVERT(DATETIME, @InvoiceDateStart, 102) AND Rec.INVOICE_DATE <= CONVERT(DATETIME, @InvoiceDateEnd, 102))
                 AND (NOT (Shipper.PACKLIST_ID IS NULL))
```

Comment: Post the *exact* error you get. Message, type, etc.

Comment: I'd ask how you're sure it's the `DATEDIFF` specifically. Since `select DATEDIFF(day,'00010101','99991231')` returns a "sensible" answer (3652058 for the curious) and encompasses the entire range of dates that SQL Server supports

Comment: From Access 2016 VBA runtime:

Comment: From Access 2016 VBA runtime:Run-time error '6'; Overflow

Comment: `CAST(Rec.INVOICE_ID AS datetime)` looks *highly* suspicious at a cursory glance. Especially when that table also has a `INVOICE_DATE` column...

Comment: Seems like I have seen this before, and I think it had to do with a date field being NULL or bad string for a date.

Comment: *[edit]* your question to add more details. Don't try pasting large chunks of e.g. error messages into the comments

Comment: When you run it from SSMS (management studio), there is no problem then?

Comment: The error occurs on a line in the error handling code that assigns the Err value to an integer variable.  intErrNum = Err

Comment: As Damien wrote - casting InvoiceID to datetime just looks wrong and is the most likely source of your error.

Comment: Damien:  I replaced the datediff with a simple 1>=0 condition in each CASE and the sp worked fine.  That caused me to suspect a problem in the datediff.  Possibly with the datatype.  There are no null dates in the columns referenced in the datediffs.

Comment: Err is a variable in VBA, so you should probably include some of the VBA code in your question. (Are you sure Err is a number?)
The problem may not be the datediff, but the fact that you are changing the `where` clause which can then return different rows in the result set.

Comment: I removed the CAST function from the dates in DATEDIFF. Ran the query in mgt studio.  Got this error: Msg 241, Level 16, State 1, Line 1
Conversion failed when converting date and/or time from character string.

Comment: Have you tried the changing INVOICE_ID to INVOICE_DATE in that function as Damien suggested? That would definitely cause that error.

Comment: Damien and Eval opened my eyes.  I should have been datediffing with INVOICE_DATE, NOT INVOICE_ID.  A case of too many hours in front of these monitors.  Thanks, all!  It works now.